# Why doesn't LinkedHashMap provide access by index?

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

From Javadoc:
`Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries.`

If it is so, then why doesn't it provide object access like List in java, 
list.get(index);

**UPDATE**

I had implemented LRU Cache using LinkedHashMap. My algorithm required me to access LRU Object from the cache. That's why I required random access, but I think that will cost me bad performance, so I have changed the logic and I am accessing the LRU object just when Cache is full...using removeEldestEntry()

Thank you all...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**a)** Because the entries are linked, not randomly accessible. The performance would be miserable, `O(N)` if I'm not in error.

**b)** Because there is no interface to back up this functionality. So the choice would be to either introduce a dedicated interface just for this (badly performing) Implementation or require clients to program against implementation classes instead of interfaces

---

Btw with [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) there's a simple solution for you:

```
Iterables.get(map.values(), offset);
```

And for caching look at Guava's [`MapMaker`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) and it's expiration features.

Comment: Thanks Sean. I'm using LinkedHashMap for implementing LRU Cache...and wanted some functionality to peek LRU object...but I guess iterating over map would be very bad performance...Do you know any other data structure for such functionality?

Comment: +1, good answer. However, it should be noted that it wouldn't be any worse than the performance provided by, say, `LinkedList`, so I don't really see the argument.

Comment: @Eternal Noob, it says in the docs: *This kind of map is well-suited to building LRU caches.*, and, *iterating* over the map is as efficient as it gets (O(n))

Comment: @aioobe which is why LinkedList doesn't implement RandomAccess

Answer (score 7):

Since `values()` provides a backing collection of the values, you can solve it like this:

```
map.values().remove(map.values().toArray()[index]);
```

Perhaps not very efficient (especially memory-wise), but it should be `O(N)` just as you would expect it to be.

---

Btw, I think the question is legitimate for all `List` operations. (It shouldn't be slower than `LinkedList` anyway, right?)

I set out to do a `LinkedHashMapList` which extended the `LinkedHashMap` and implemented the `List` interface. Surprisingly it seems impossible to do, due to the clash for remove. The existing `remove` method returns the previously mapped object, while the `List.remove` should return a `boolean`.

That's just a reflection, and honestly, I also find it annoying that the `LinkedHashMap` can't be treated more like a `LinkedList`.

Comment: ya, I saw that too... remove() method for LinkedHashMap is coming from HashMap as LinkedHashMap extends HashMap...and that's conflicting with List's remove()...

Answer (score 1):

It provides an `Iterator` interface, each node in the list is linked to the one before it and after it. Having a `get(i)` method would be no different than iterating over all the elements in the list since there is no backing array (same as `LinkedList`).

If you require this ability which isn't very performant I suggest extending the map yourself

Comment: So, in linked list, whenever we access last element, list.get(list.size()-1), is it a random access or O(n) (all the elements are iterated)?

Comment: `It provides an Iterator interface` that's not correct. The map's entrySet() provides the iterator, not the Map itself (but apart from that you're right)

Comment: @EternalNoob it’s an old comment, but for future readers it’s worth answering your old question: the `LinkedList` knows its size and will iterate backwards when you access an element index higher than the list’s half. So accessing the last element is as cheap as accessing the first element. Only elements in the middle have the expense of iteration.

Answer (score 1):

If you want random access you can do

```
Map<K,V> map = new LinkedHashMap<K,V>();
Map.Entry<K,V>[] entries = (Map.Entry<K,V>[]) map.toArray(new Map.Entry[map.size()]);
Map.Entry<K,V> entry_n = entry[n];
```

As you can see the performance is likely to be very poor unless you cache the `entries` array.

I would question the need for it however.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real problem to make a Map with log(N) efficiency of access by index. If you use a red-black tree and store for each node the number of elements in the tree starting at that node it is possible to write a get(int index) method that is log(N).

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question.