# How to get position of key/value in LinkedHashMap using its key

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I have a `LinkedHashMap` (called info) that contains name/age (string/int) pairs. How can I get the position of the key/value if I input the key? For example, if my `LinkedHashMap` looked like this `{bob=12, jeremy=42, carly=21}` and I was to search `jeremy`, it should return `1` as its in position 1. I was hoping I can use something like `info.getIndex("jeremy")`.

Comment: See [why-doesnt-linkedhashmap-provide-access-by-index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666820/why-doesnt-linkedhashmap-provide-access-by-index)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`HashMap` implementations in general are un-ordered for `Iteration`.

`LinkedHashMap` is **predictablely** ordered for `Iteration` ( insertion order ) but does not expose the `List` interface and a `LinkedList` ( which is what mirrors the key set insertion order ) does not track index position itself either, it is very in-efficient to find the index as well. The `LinkedHashMap` doesn't expose the reference to the internal `LinkedList` either.

> The actual *"Linked List"* behavior is implementation specific. Some
>   may actually use an instance of `LinkedList` some many just have
>   `Entry` track a previous and next `Entry` and use that as its
>   implementation. Don't assume anything without looking at the source.

The `KeySet` that contains the keys does not guarantee order as well because of the hashing algorithms used for placement in the backing data structure of the inherited `HashMap`. So you can't use that.

The only way to do this, without writing your own implementation, is to walk the `Iterator` which uses the mirroring `LinkedList` and keep a count where you are, this will be very in-efficient with large data sets.

**Solution**

What it sounds like you want is **original insertion order index positions**, you would have to mirror the keys in the `KeySet` in something like an `ArrayList`, keep it in sync with updates to the `HashMap` and use it for finding position. Creating a sub-class of `HashMap`, say `IndexedHashMap` and adding this `ArrayList` internally and adding a `.getKeyIndex(<K> key)` that delegates to the internal `ArrayList` `.indexOf()` is probably the best way to go about this.

This is what `LinkedHashMap` does but with a `LinkedList` mirroring the `KeySet` instead of an `ArrayList`.

Comment: I thought LinkedHashMap retains the order. Is there any thing I can use that can store key/value but retain the order?

Comment: It retains, *order* but does not track *position*.

Comment: @HernánEche read the question and the answer for comprehension, they want to track position as well, which I go into detail about in my answer.

Comment: @HernánEche the *order* of a `HashSet` *can* change on every insert or deletion, it isn't guaranteed, so yes I am correct, you can't use that!

Answer (score 28):

```
int pos = new ArrayList<String>(info.keySet()).indexOf("jeremy")
```

Comment: Ignore the above comments. `keySet()` order for `LinkedHashMap` is guaranteed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923856/is-the-order-guaranteed-for-the-return-of-keys-and-values-from-a-linkedhashmap-o.

Answer (score 5):

I saw a suggestion from one of the duplicates of this question at

[How get value from LinkedHashMap based on index not on key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581997/how-get-value-from-linkedhashmap-based-on-index-not-on-key)

and I liked the suggestion as described as pseudo code from @schippi in the comments.  I thought some working Java code might be useful to others on this approach

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class IndexedLinkedHashMap<K,V> extends LinkedHashMap<K,V> {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    ArrayList<K> al_Index = new ArrayList<K>();

    @Override
    public V put(K key,V val) {
        if (!super.containsKey(key)) al_Index.add(key);
        V returnValue = super.put(key,val);
        return returnValue;
    }

    public V getValueAtIndex(int i){
        return (V) super.get(al_Index.get(i));
    }

    public K getKeyAtIndex(int i) {
        return (K) al_Index.get(i);
    }

    public int getIndexOf(K key) {
        return al_Index.indexOf(key);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that LinkedHashMap keep the order of insertion, you can use the keySet() and List.copyOf() (since Java 10) methods like this:

```
List<String> keys = List.copyOf( yourLinkedHashMap.keySet() );

System.out.println( keys.indexOf("jeremy") ); // prints '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

LinkedHashMap has "predictable iteration order" ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)).  Items don't know their location, though, so you'll have to iterate the collection to get it.  If you're maintaining a large map you may want to use a different structure for storage.

Edit: clarified iteration

Comment: *"walking the key `Set` won't do you any good, it is backed by a `Set`, and it is un-ordered. The `LinkedList` is only used for the `Iterator`. [When in doubt use the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.keySet%28%29).

Comment: Indeed.  I meant entry set.  That's why a quoted the iteration order bit...implied iterator usage.  Poor choice of words on my part.

Comment: The first paragraph in the javadoc says it's in insert order, which is exactly what he asked for.  I think we're saying the same thing here, anyway.  The edits have made your answer clearer.

Comment: they want the position by **key** in insertion order, you can't get that without using the `Iterator` with a stock `LinkedHashMap`. Neither the keyset or entryset will individually give what they are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`com.google.common.collect.LinkedListMultimap`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) from the **Google Guava library**. You don't need the multimap behaviour of this class what you want is that the `keys()` method guarantees they are returned in insertion order and can then be used to construct a List, you can use the `indexOf()` to find the required index position

Answer (score 0):

I do extract the positons of the key into a concurent map like this:

Here for a Map, someListOfComplexObject() would be entrySet()
and getComplexStringKeyElem() would be getKey()

might come from

```
 final int[] index = {0};
 Stream<ComplexObject> t = someListOfComplexObject.stream();
 ConcurrentMap<String, List<Integer>> m = 
      t.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
           e -> e.getComplexStringKeyElem(),
           Collectors.mapping(
                e -> index[0]++,
                Collectors.toList()
           ),
           ConcurrentSkipListMap::new));
```